# How to show that any $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is continuous if the topological space $X$ has a discrete topology.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How do you SHOW that if $X$ (a topological space) has the discrete topology, then any $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is continous?

I know that the discrete topology has to have all sets as open, as it already contains all sets

I know that every subspace of a topological space with the discrete topology has the discrete topology.

So does this mean that every preimage of an open set is open? And the discrete topology has nothing but open sets?

How exactly do I show it?

Comment: What is there left to be shown? It seems you got stuck after crossing the finish line

Comment: Recall the definition: $f \colon X \rightarrow Y$ is open iff the preimage of any open set in $Y$ is an open subset of $X$. But every subset of $X$ is open...

Answer (score 1):

You're already there. A function $f \colon X \to Y$ is continuous if the subset $f^{-1}(U)$ of $X$ is open for every open subset $U$ of $Y$. But *every* subset of $X$ is open, since $X$ has the discrete topology.